# How to draw dashed polyline with android google map sdk v2?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, google-maps-android-api-2

I've looked through the [documentation of polyline](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polyline) and there is no option to make it dashed.

Do anybody know how to draw dashed polyline with android google map sdk v2?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is not possible in current release. Follow this issue for updates: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4633

**UPDATE**

Recently, Google implemented this feature for polylines in Google Maps Android API v2 and marked issue 4633 as Fixed.

See information about stroke patterns in the [Shapes Guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/shapes#stroke_pattern). See an [example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/polygon-tutorial#add_custom_styling_to_your_polygon) in the Polylines and Polygons tutorial.

You can also read the corresponding blog post here:

https://maps-apis.googleblog.com/2017/02/styling-and-custom-data-for-polylines.html

Comment: This was marked as the 'accepted answer' with its "update note" saying quoted: "Google implemented this feature for polylines in Google Maps Android API v2 ... " . That is NOT TRUE. It is not extra/support nor extension for v2. What is true is they released new Map API V.10.2.1 (02/2017) that addressed the issue 4633 providing patterns (dash/dot/etc.) to Polylines. In no way that it would still support v2. To use it, you must replace the entire v2 with the new version, and possibly recode your map classes implementations.

Comment: thanks you post url https://maps-apis.googleblog.com/2017/02/styling-and-custom-data-for-polylines.html is help me and work for me.

Comment: I have checked the docs but I haven't found the way to round the dashes of the polyline. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 29):

Now in Polyline you can set the pattern to be Dash, Dot or Gap
simply apply the following

```
public static final int PATTERN_DASH_LENGTH_PX = 20;
public static final int PATTERN_GAP_LENGTH_PX = 20;
public static final PatternItem DOT = new Dot();
public static final PatternItem DASH = new Dash(PATTERN_DASH_LENGTH_PX);
public static final PatternItem GAP = new Gap(PATTERN_GAP_LENGTH_PX);
public static final List<PatternItem> PATTERN_POLYGON_ALPHA = Arrays.asList(GAP, DASH);

 private void drawDashedLeg(GoogleMap googleMap, Route route) {
    PolylineOptions polyOptions = new PolylineOptions();
    polyOptions.color(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.coolgrey));
    polyOptions.addAll(route.getPoints());
    polyOptions.pattern(PATTERN_POLYGON_ALPHA);
    Polyline polyline = googleMap.addPolyline(polyOptions);
    polylines.add(polyline);
}
```

Comment: @atabouraya Thanks broi

Answer (score 14):

Alexey, I've just created a function that worked for me and I think that will help you:

```
public static void createDashedLine(GoogleMap map, LatLng latLngOrig, LatLng latLngDest, int color){
    double difLat = latLngDest.latitude - latLngOrig.latitude;
    double difLng = latLngDest.longitude - latLngOrig.longitude;

    double zoom = map.getCameraPosition().zoom;

    double divLat = difLat / (zoom * 2);
    double divLng = difLng / (zoom * 2);

    LatLng tmpLatOri = latLngOrig;

    for(int i = 0; i < (zoom * 2); i++){
        LatLng loopLatLng = tmpLatOri;

        if(i > 0){
            loopLatLng = new LatLng(tmpLatOri.latitude + (divLat * 0.25f), tmpLatOri.longitude + (divLng * 0.25f));
        }

        Polyline polyline = map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
            .add(loopLatLng)
            .add(new LatLng(tmpLatOri.latitude + divLat, tmpLatOri.longitude + divLng))
            .color(color)
            .width(5f));

        tmpLatOri = new LatLng(tmpLatOri.latitude + divLat, tmpLatOri.longitude + divLng);
    }
}
```

Comment: hi i am using this same method its working fine.. but zooming that dashed line also getting large.. do u know while zooming also it display the same dashed line size?..

Comment: @user, a solution could be the creation of a List to store all the Polylines (List<Polyline>) that compound our "Dashed Line" and create a method to set the width of all the Polylines in that List for every zoom in/out.

Comment: when you have a lot of line(1k) will this method slowdown the app?

Comment: This mehod is slow and computational slow even on modern phones, even if it seems the only one possible with v2 api

Comment: This works well, however, how to clear lines with updates?

Answer (score 9):

I created the following function to draw dotted polyline with a list of LatLng points.
This algorithm creates lines of 0.002 kms (followed by 0.002 kms meter gaps) irrespective of zoom. This is useful when you don't want to re-plot polylines when zoom changes.

```
private void drawDashedPolyLine(GoogleMap mMap, ArrayList<LatLng> listOfPoints, int color) {
    /* Boolean to control drawing alternate lines */
    boolean added = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfPoints.size() - 1 ; i++) {
        /* Get distance between current and next point */
        double distance = getConvertedDistance(listOfPoints.get(i),listOfPoints.get(i + 1));

        /* If distance is less than 0.002 kms */
        if (distance < 0.002) {
            if (!added) {
                mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                        .add(listOfPoints.get(i))
                        .add(listOfPoints.get(i + 1))
                        .color(color));
                added = true;
            } else {/* Skip this piece */
                added = false;
            }
        } else {
            /* Get how many divisions to make of this line */
            int countOfDivisions = (int) ((distance/0.002));

            /* Get difference to add per lat/lng */
            double latdiff = (listOfPoints.get(i+1).latitude - listOfPoints
                    .get(i).latitude) / countOfDivisions;
            double lngdiff = (listOfPoints.get(i + 1).longitude - listOfPoints
                    .get(i).longitude) / countOfDivisions;

            /* Last known indicates start point of polyline. Initialized to ith point */
            LatLng lastKnowLatLng = new LatLng(listOfPoints.get(i).latitude, listOfPoints.get(i).longitude);
            for (int j = 0; j < countOfDivisions; j++) {

                /* Next point is point + diff */
                LatLng nextLatLng = new LatLng(lastKnowLatLng.latitude + latdiff, lastKnowLatLng.longitude + lngdiff);
                if (!added) {
                    mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                    .add(lastKnowLatLng)
                    .add(nextLatLng)
                    .color(color));
                    added = true;
                } else {
                    added = false;
                }
                lastKnowLatLng = nextLatLng;
            }
        }
    }
}

private double getConvertedDistance(LatLng latlng1, LatLng latlng2) {
    double distance = DistanceUtil.distance(latlng1.latitude,
            latlng1.longitude,
            latlng2.latitude,
            latlng2.longitude);
    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(distance);
    BigDecimal res = bd.setScale(3, RoundingMode.DOWN);
    return res.doubleValue();
}
```

Util class to calculate distance between two LatLng:

```
public class DistanceUtil {

    public static double distance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2,
        double lon2) {

    if ((lat1 == lat2) && (lon1 == lon2)) {
        return 0;
    } else
        return distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, 'K');
    }

    public static double distance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2,
        double lon2, char unit) {
        double theta = lon1 - lon2;
        double dist = Math.sin(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.sin(deg2rad(lat2))
            + Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2))
            * Math.cos(deg2rad(theta));
        dist = Math.acos(dist);
        dist = rad2deg(dist);
        dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
        if (unit == 'K') {
            dist = dist * 1.609344;
        } else if (unit == 'N') {
            dist = dist * 0.8684;
        }
        return (dist);
    }

    private static double deg2rad(double deg) {
        return (deg * Math.PI / 180.0);
    }

    private static double rad2deg(double rad) {
        return (rad * 180.0 / Math.PI);
    }
}
```

Note: The above algorithm generates very large number of polylines which may take time to render. It is useful only when the list of points is small.

Comment: I use you algo with 0.02 km and incremented int k in the loop: if (k%2==0) {addPopyline..} to get b/w dotted line