# Google Mapv2 Drawing dotted path

Tags: android-maps-v2

I want to draw path on map from source to destination as dotted Form.I have draw path as line .but requirement is dotted form.

Comment: Can you add some more details of what have you tried?

Comment: i have draw path using PolylineOptions as line but i need as dotted line.....as this

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13721008/how-to-draw-dashed-polyline-with-android-google-map-sdk-v2

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-symbol-dashed

It's called a dashed line instead of dotted

Edit: if you insist on round symbols as "dotted path" (if you google "dotted line" you will get dashed lines as well so it was confusing) I sugged you use the round symbol [google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/symbols#predefined) and fill it

Comment: i need as dotted form.

Comment: @user3095020 what you call dotted is actually called dashed. Or just make the length of the dashes shorter so they are round if that is your goal

Comment: @user3095020 edited my answer to suit your need better

Comment: This is Javascipt API. I think the OP is using the Android Maps API

Comment: @ExceptionAl you should be able to pass the icon argument, so it's still relevant

Comment: This answer is for Javascript, the question is tagged "android"!

Comment: @Thomas, not at all, unfortunately. There is even a request for this feature on Google Maps issues for Android: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4633. Therefore, it does not exist for Android, but for *Javascript* it does, as shown in your answer.