# how to draw curved line between two points in google maps android?

Tags: android, maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-android-api-1

i want to draw curved line between two points,can any one help me? i used poly line Geodesic but the curve is not that much visible,can i increase the curve size using Geodesic?

Comment: do you want to draw route between two points?

Comment: yes but curved line. i already using polyline but polyline curve not that much visible.

Comment: You should have to try this:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/34133503/6096821

Comment: This is for Javascript.can you please tell me for android.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I draw a curved dashed line in Google Maps Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43305664/can-i-draw-a-curved-dashed-line-in-google-maps-android)

Answer (score -1):

Check this:

```
           ArrayList<LatLng> poi = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
           PolylineOptions polyLineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
           poi.add(new LatLng(-33.66855343,151.2958685)); //from
           poi.add(new LatLng(-33.66961962,151.3114906)); // to
           polyLineOptions.width(7);
           polyLineOptions.geodesic(true);
           polyLineOptions.color(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
           polyLineOptions.addAll(points);
           Polyline polyline = mGoogleMap.addPolyline(polyLineOptions);
           polyline.setGeodesic(true);
```

Comment: This only adds a straight line